# How to make wow fadeInUp work with overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css, wow.js

I have a little problem when i try to add `wow fadeInUp` (https://wowjs.uk/docs) animation on my website. I have
`overflow` set to `scroll` in my css and it seems to disable the effects of the animation. There is a reason why i had it on scroll so i was wondering if there is a way to make it work with `overflow: scroll;`

Here is the website for more details: https://admiring-khorana-ad08d5.netlify.app/

```css
.webContainer{
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="webContainer">
<div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item text wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="3s"><img class="services-icon img" src="./icons/services/s1.png" alt=""> <a
                class="servicesTag" href="">Acupuncture</a><br>
              <div class="serv-description">
                Cette pratique constitue tout acte de stimulation, généralement au
                moyen d’aiguilles, de certains sites déterminés sur la peau.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item text wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="3s"> <img class="services-icon img" src="./icons/services/s2.png" alt=""> <a
                class="servicesTag" href="">Kinésiologie</a><br>
              <div class="serv-description">
                Le kinésiologue est le professionnel de la santé expert en activité
                physique. Il vous accompagne dans l’adoption et le maintien d’un
                style de vie sain et actif. Ce professionnel peut aussi vous aider à
                perdre du poids. Les programmes d’entraînement conçus par les
                kinésiologues peuvent aussi aider les personnes souffrant de
                problèmes chroniques.
              </div>
            </div>

...
```

```js
  var wow = new WOW();
  wow.init();
```

Comment: Have you tried `@keyframes`?

Comment: @YT_Xaos i would have to code all the animation myself in that case?

Comment: Well I always use `@keyframes` when I put animations cus I don't know anything else that makes animations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you are talking about but you can use `@keyframes fadeIn` to make animations. Example:

```css
p:hover {
    animation: fadeIn 3.1s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Does that answer your question

Comment: The thing is, the effects needs to be a fadeInUp, not just a fadeIn, and it needs to happen on scroll! I dont think css could detect a "onScroll"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using Jquery

```js
    if (scrolled > 25 && scrolled < 50) {
      jQuery('.grid-item, .services-image').each(function(i) {
          setTimeout(()=>{
            $(this).show().addClass('animated fadeInUp')
          }, 250 * i);
      });
```